# onClickListener only works after several clicks

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I know this is not a very good problem description, but I stumbled into unstable behavior of my ListAdapter.

The point is, onItemClickListener in my application only responds if furiously clicked sereral times. Debugger also only responds in such situation. Nevertheless, from time to time clicks work just fine. It seems as if something is preventing internally the onItemClickListener from bein called. Sometimes even the default android click animation is not shown on first click. Although, after 2-5 clicks fast one after another is always works as expected.

Being new to Android development, I have no idea where to start looking for the problem. Problem is not device-specific (tested).

Just in case, some code from my project (although I'm not even sure what to provide):

**Some code from OffersListAdapter:**

```
class ViewHolder {
    private TextView whoandWhom;
    private TextView date;
    private TextView distance;

    private TextView status;
    private TextView place;

    private boolean isMeeting = false;
    private Meeting.Status meetingStatus;

    private void color(int color) {
        for (Field v: this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                if (v.getType() == TextView.class) {
                    TextView view = (TextView) v.get(this);
                    view.setTextColor(res.getColor(color));
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "This field does not exist");
            }
        }
    }
}
private View prepareHolder(boolean isMeeting, View convertView, Meeting.Status mStatus, Offer offer) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (isMeeting) {
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.meetings_item, null);
    } else {
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.offers_item, null);
    }
    holder.whoandWhom = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.datetime);
    holder.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTime);
    holder.distance = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance);

    if (isMeeting) {
        holder.isMeeting = true;
        holder.status = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(status);
        holder.place = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(place);
        holder.meetingStatus = mStatus;
    }

    convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.whoandWhom.setText(offer.getOwnership());
    holder.date.setText(offer.getDateRepresentation());
    String distance = new DecimalFormat("#####.##").format(offer.getDistance()) + " км";
    holder.distance.setText(distance);

    if (isMeeting) {
        Meeting meeting = (Meeting) offer;
        holder.place.setText(meeting.getPlace_name());
        switch (meeting.getStatus()) {
            case pending:
                holder.status.setText("Очікує підтвердження");
                break;
            case upcoming:
                holder.status.setText("Незабаром");
                holder.color(R.color.colorAccent);
                break;
            case completed:
                holder.status.setText("Завершено");
                holder.color(R.color.colorPrimary);
                break;
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    Offer offer = this.getItem(position);
    Boolean isMeeting = offer.getClass() == Meeting.class;

    Meeting.Status status = null;
    if (isMeeting)
        status = ((Meeting) offer).getStatus();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = prepareHolder(isMeeting, convertView, status, offer);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        if (isMeeting != holder.isMeeting)
            convertView = prepareHolder(isMeeting, convertView, status, offer);
        else if (isMeeting) {
            if (status != holder.meetingStatus)
                convertView = prepareHolder(true, convertView, status, offer);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

**Some methods from MainActivity:**

```
private void configureOffersOutput() {
    offersOutput = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.offersOutput);
    offersList = new ArrayList<Offer>();

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    loadingView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_footer_view, null);

    adapter = new OffersListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), offersList, getResources());

    configureOnItemClick();
    offersOutput.setAdapter(adapter);

    offersOutput.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    offersOutput.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (view.getLastVisiblePosition() >= totalItemCount - 1 && !isLoading) {
                moreOffers();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void configureOnItemClick() {

    final Activity a = this;

    offersOutput.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final Offer item = offersList.get(position);
            if (item.getClass() == Offer.class) {

                openActivity(a, SuggestActivity.class, new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                    put("id", item.getId());
                    put("location", item.getLocation());
                    put("datetime", item.getDateRepresentation());
                    put("ownership", item.getOwnership());

                    put("currentCoordinates", coordinates);
                    put("token", user.getToken());
                    put("uid", user.getId());
                }});

            } else if (item.getClass() == Meeting.class) {

                final Meeting meeting = (Meeting) item;
                Class<?> name;

                switch (meeting.getStatus()) {
                    case pending:
                        name = ApproveActivity.class;
                        break;
                    case upcoming:
                        name = UpcomingActivity.class;
                        break;
                    case completed:
                        name = RateActivity.class;
                        break;
                    default:
                        name = MeetingActivity.class;
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Wrong status: " + meeting.getStatus().toString());
                }

                final String distance = new DecimalFormat("#####.##").format(meeting.getDistance()) + " км";

                openActivity(a, name, new HashMap<String, String>(){{
                    put("id", meeting.getId());
                    put("datetime", meeting.getDateRepresentation());
                    put("ownership", meeting.getOwnership());

                    put("tel", meeting.getTel());
                    put("distance", distance);
                    put("place", meeting.getPlace_name());
                    put("place_coordinates", meeting.getPlace_coordinates());

                    put("currentCoordinates", coordinates);
                    put("token", user.getToken());
                    put("uid", user.getId());
                }});

            }
        }
    });

    initRefresh();

    isSetItemOnClick = true;
}
```

Comment: where is your onclick listener

Comment: Please post you onClickListener,
Also this was happen to me before and it was because I implement a two listeners from the activity and from the adapter for the same view.

Comment: offersOutput.setonItemClickListerner ?

Comment: @GunduBandagar, I added the method to the post

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out an answer just in case someone has the same problem.

Besides all this, I had a method responding to scroll events. It would load the data on scroll down like this:

```
ffersOutput.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    offersOutput.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (view.getLastVisiblePosition() >= totalItemCount - 1 && !isLoading) {
                moreOffers();
            }
        }
    });
```

`moreOffers` would than send a request to backend and load the rows.

The problem was:

1. DB ran out of rows very quickly, so it would receive empty results
2. App sent requests so quickly and tried refreshing rows so often that they most of the time wouldn't be able to respond to touches.

Solution (although ugly):
Add to the method which receives data from DB something like this:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        isLoading = false;
    }
}, 100);
```

That prevents app from making requests so often, so it can respond.